# Do I need to create/deploy both a digitalproperty-network and digitalproperty-model in my repository or can they just be a single project?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

(Question is being recorded for future use)

I can see two repositories in the fabric-composer github organisation, one `sample-models` (https://github.com/fabric-composer/sample-models) and the other `sample-networks` (https://github.com/fabric-composer/sample-networks). Can the model and the network both be stored in the same repository?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, storing a network and model in the same repository is fine